# Как перетаскивать объекты в PictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Вот, скажите, я захотел сделать свой Map Editor (хочу сделать свой 2Д движок РПГ), но вот беда: не могу я его сделать. Вот у меня форма (заготовка)

[image]

И я хочу сделать так, чтобы из одного PictureBox'a можно было перетаскивать выделенные объекты на другой... как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы пореокмендовал начать не с пользовательского интерфейса, а с организации данных.

У класса Bitmap есть методы GetPixel / SetPixel. Можете копировать по пикселю.

Comment: А можно небольшой пример?

Comment: А я бы порекомендовал посмотреть в сторону DragNDrop'а..

Comment: Да но мне надо не каждый PictureBox перетаскивать, а содержимое.